# Is it possible to run code when the object in WeakReference is garbage collected?

Tags: java

I would like to do something like this:

```java
class MyWeakReference<T> extends WeakReference<T> {

  void onClear() { .. run my code .. }
}
```

But since GC doesn't call `clear()`, but sets the referent to null directly, it seems like there is no way to invoke such code.

Comment: If you register it with a `reference queue` you could then set a timer and periodically check if it has been `enqueued()`.  Then you could run your code.  In fact, you could write you own listener and register it and have a background process monitor the status.

Comment: See [`java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) or [`java.lang.ref.Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) (Java 9+).